# Vector/linear algebra Plane Question english explanation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not a native English speaker but I study a vector/linear algebra course in English. I am having trouble understanding what this particular question actually means. I have seen the solution and I know how to get there but I am not sure what I am actually doing or what the question wants me to do. I managed to solve this by following calculations of a similar example question.

"In Exercises 73-76, find a point-normal form of the equation of the plane passing through P and having n as a normal"
P(2,3,-4) n=(1,-1,2)

Comment: Do you know what "point-normal" means?

Comment: What do you mean by a *point-normal form*?

Comment: I know that normal is a orthogonal vector to the plane, I do not know what point normal mean

Comment: A simple internet search for “point-normal form” turns up [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/point-normal-form-of-a-plane), [this](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-point-normal-form-of-the-equation-of-a-plane), [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-b-matrices-and-systems-of-equations/session-12-equations-of-planes-ii/MIT18_02SC_notes_5.pdf) and many other sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point in the plane and $\vec{n}=\langle n_x,n_y,n_z\rangle$ is normal to the plane, then the point-normal equation for the plane is
$$
n_x(x-x_0)+n_y(y-y_0)+n_z(z-z_0)=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane, then the vector $(x-2,y-3,z+4)$ is a vector in the plane. Therefore the dot product of the vector and the normal vector is $0$ so we get $(x-2)-(y-3)+2(z+4)=0$(This is the point normal form) which is the same as $x-2-y+3+2z+8=0$ which is the same as $x-y+2z=-9$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation of the plane: ax+by+cz=c. This is of the form f(x,y,z)=c, which is level to the the function f(x,y,z). Since the gradient $\nabla$f(x,y,z) is always perpendicular to the level of a function. So that means that the normal is $<a,b,c>$. Do you know how to find the equation of the plane?